# Screen Scrape through login with Curl and PHP

Tags: php, curl, authentication, screen-scraping, scrape

I have been reading curl screen scraping information for hours and I can't seem to figure out what I am doing right or wrong.  I am not sure how to tell if my login attempts work or not.

The goal is "simple", post to the login page then pull data from a page past the login.

From that I can tell from Tamper Data is the site seems to use mainly post params for webpage navigation, so I am making two curl requests.  One to login, and one to get the HTML from the page. So far the dump I get is this:

*string(7097) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: sp21webs=a11a060bf1DELETED000064000000; expires=Mon, 21-Oct-2013 01:47:02 GMT; path=/
Server: ""
Date: Mon, 21 Oct 2013 01:37:01 GMT
Content-type: text/html
Last-modified: Sun, 13 Oct 2013 21:54:39 GMT
Content-length: 6781
Etag: "1a7d-DELETED69f"
Accept-ranges: bytes*

With what looks like the login page HTML

I am not very familiar with how Curl works, here is my code:

```
$submit_url = "https://okbnetplaza.com/WBIG0001.html"; 

$curl = curl_init(); 
$cookie = 'cookies.txt';
$params = array (
   "__uid" => "<hidden>",
   "PIN" => "<hidden>",
   "__type" => "0001",
   "__gid" => "WBIG0001",
   "__func" => "%A3%CF%A3%CB",
   "__func2" => "%A5%ED%A5%B0%A5%A4%A5%F3",
   "RegType" => "0",
 );

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ; 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params ); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url); 
$result = curl_exec($curl); 

var_dump($result); 
curl_close($curl); 

echo "<h1> Login Work????</h1>";

$urltopost = "https://okbnetplaza.com/WBIG0001.html";
$datatopost = array (
   "__type" => "0033",
   "__gid" => "WBIG0005",
   "__func" => "%A3%CF%A3%CB",
   "AccountListType" => "1",
   "DispAccountInfo" => "00000000000000000000",
);

$ch = curl_init ($urltopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$returndata = curl_exec ($ch);
var_dump($returndata);
```

- I am not 100% sure the URLs are correct because the site using confusing JS

The Question:
My current code, does not seem to get through the login page.  Do you see any issues with my curl requests that would stop the login?  Do you see any want to make the login and scraping to work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Dagon - if they wanted me logging in they would create an API :) From what I read it should be possible, I just need the right setup.

Comment: What's the question? Maybe try a library like snoopy or pgbrowser.

Comment: LOL, I am dumb for not asking a question.  These are new libraries to me I am going to try out snoopy right now.  Thanks!

Comment: I gave snoopy and pgbrowser a try last night. No success yet, I still want to try a couple things before I give up. Any recommendations are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an FYI,

I ended up using [casperjs](http://casperjs.org/), then calling the script via exec with a PHP script.

Not perfect, but it is the best way to mimic browsing behavior that I could find.